# Finding variable contribution in manova

Tags: r, anova, manova

I have a dataset with one grouping factor and some dependent continuous variables. Given the difference, I want to know which variables contribute the most to the difference, like this variable A is the most impactful, that variable B is actually not necessary, etc. I have read some articles and suppose MANOVA can do such things, but I am not sure of how to do it (coding and interpretation).

Could anyone kindly guide me to the relevant information/questions?

Example: I will reproduce what I intend to do

```
iris_variables = iris[, 1:4]
adonis(iris_variables ~ iris$Species,permutation = 999)

              Df SumsOfSqs MeanSqs F.Model      R2 Pr(>F)    
iris$Species   2   2.31730 1.15865  532.74 0.87876  0.001 ***
Residuals    147   0.31971 0.00217         0.12124           
Total        149   2.63701                 1.00000
```

The results show the significant difference between species, but I want to know which variables contributed the most to this classification. Out of four variables (Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width), which one is the most distinctive and which ones are not.

Comment: (M)ANOVA is not a classification tool, so this cannot be answered. You would need to use an actual classification model if you wanted to answer your question.

Comment: What you describe in your first paragraph sounds different from what you describe at the end. Are you interested in understaning the impact of Species on your different outcomes, or are you interested in understaning hoe the other 4 variables help in classifying/predicting a certain Species? That would be an entirely different analysis and you‘d need to switch the „causal“ direction.

Comment: thank you so much for all the comments! I have edited the question to clarify some of my points. I am interested in understanding how the other 4 variables help in classifying/predicting a certain species (borrowing deschen's words). Is manova not an appropriate tool? If not, what would be more suitable?